# How does the python -m prefix in command work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am very new to Python programming. I can use `pip install` without any trouble. I've seen a lot of posts in online which prefix `pip install` with `python -m`. When I use `python -m` before the pip command nothing seems to happen. Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `python -h`, the `-m` flag is described as:

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

In this case, when you run `python -m pip` Python runs the `pip` module as a script (i.e. it executes the code inside it). If you have added `pip` to your [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) you can then just run `pip` directly without the need to invoke it via `python`.

`python -m pip install <some module>` and `pip install <some module>` should perform identically. If you have multiple versions of Python installed on your system, using `pip` might install a module for the wrong version of Python. You can check the version using `pip -V` which will output something like

```
pip 18.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

here the python version is `python3.7`.

If the version of the `pip` command doesn't match with the version of Python used to execute a program when the program is executed it will not run. You can check your Python version with `python -V`, which will output something like

```
Python 2.7.16
```

If the `pip` version doesn't match your Python version you can either update your path's `pip`, or you can use `python -m pip`. To select the correct version (i.e. if `python` runs Python 2 and you want to use Python 3) just execute `python3 -m pip` or `python3.7 -m pip`.